# AWS Aurora/MySQL server crashes with spatial query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using AWS Aurora/MySQL, engine version `5.7.mysql_aurora.2.09.0` and we have a spatial index on a table with ~10,000,000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  ...
  `lat` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `geo_polyline` linestring DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `geo_location` point GENERATED ALWAYS AS (point(`lng`,`lat`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  ...
  SPATIAL KEY `geo_location_index` (`geo_location`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When we do a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  from `foo`
where
        st_intersects(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((16.2 48.1, 16.4 48.1, 16.4 48.2, 16.2 48.2, 16.2 48.1))'), geo_polyline)
    and
        st_contains(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((16.2 48.1, 16.4 48.1, 16.4 48.2, 16.2 48.2, 16.2 48.1))'), geo_location);
```

the server crashes.  This is repeatable: it happens every time.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this and does anyone have any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: Does your server crash if you run the query with ONLY lines 1,2 and 5?

Comment: @WilsonHauck
> Does your server crash if you run the query with ONLY lines 1,2 and 5?
No it doesn't.

Comment: Could it be that you are using DATATYPEs that are not of the SPATIAL world on line 3?

Comment: Sorry, @WilsonHauck, I don't understand how a polyline or a polygon can be "not of the SPATIAL world"?

Comment: Could your column named geo_polyline become NOT NULL rather than DEFAULT NULL?   If it could be changed, then you could have an index on the column per this URL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-type-overview.html  and the query may not crash your server.  My best guess.

Comment: Or this wild idea of  .....16.2 48.2, 16.2 48.1))'), geo_polyline) TO ..... 16.2 48.2, 16.2 48.1))'), GeoFromText(geo_polyline)) on line 3 ?  Dave L - Yes, this is really just a GUESS.

Comment: @WilsonHauck that column can't be NOT NULL because in some cases it doesn't exist.

Also, your wild idea gives `ERROR 3037 (22023): Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.`

Comment: Good luck. I am out of ideas for you to try.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck.  Appreciate your efforts.